# There is no sound out of the speakers from my dell inspiron 15 3000 series laptop ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, dell, inspiron

There is no sound out of the speakers from my dell inspiron 15 3000 series laptop OS ubuntu 12.04. All of the blue there was no sound on my laptop without making any adjustments to the sound device. can you please help me fix this.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this ?